# Show only graph in htop output

Tags: output, htop

Would it be possible to show only the summary section of `htop` output?

[image]

desired look:

[image]

I have looked into the manpages but couldn't find any options to do so.
The closest thing i have found is this: http://www.softprayog.in/tutorials/htop-command-in-linux, but hat would make changes permanent, which I don't want.

Answer (score 18):

You can pretty much configure it at your will pressing S inside htop.

However, I also did not find anything to erase all the processes. But, you can call it to see only the processes as one user. So you can call it as:

```
$htop -u nobody
```

Which is actually the closest I managed to do it.

Press S.

First in "Setup", you go to "Columns", and delete all except "Command" that cannot be deleted. Finally you press F10 to leave.

If you do not wish for the changes to be permanent, run the following command before the manual steps described.

```
$chmod a-w ~/.config
```

For more ideas "Top on Steroids – 15 Practical Linux HTOP Examples"

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/linux-htop-examples/

Comment: +1 for the pressing S hint