# htop summary only display

Tags: htop

Is there a way to run `htop` but display only the graphs (I don't want to see the individual processes)? I saw [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245788/show-only-graph-in-htop-output) question which seems to suggest no - I'm wondering if that has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the same effect by asking to see only a non-existant process id, eg

```
htop -p 99999999
```

Comment: nice one. also works with top command.